# Background image isn't rendering in the web browser

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to repeat an image I have by x and y, using repeat-all. The image isn't displaying.

Here is the CSS code:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('Content/images/test.png') repeat-all;
}
```

I'm sure the CSS file is linked correctly, here is the Content folder of my application:
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually not being linked correctly, if that code is in your Site.css file. It should be:

```
background-image: url('images/test.png') repeat-all;
```